# Is there a word for technical debt that is centered around at-rest configuration data?

Tags: business-language

So sometimes my team runs into [technical debt](https://www.productplan.com/glossary/technical-debt/) centered around persistent data. A quick example is if we create four options KNOWING that we will want to reduce them to two options later. This would require a translation matrix to somehow reduce 4 options to 2 options -- some specificity must be lost in this translation, and we know that.

Is there a word for technical debt of that nature? I know usually tech debt is "this code is implemented poorly and we have to work around it", and I'm wondering if there's something different for "This data is implemented poorly/needs changed and we need to fix it"

Comment: I don't think "implemented poorly" is a good expression for the context. It's not that "technical debt-incurring" code is badly written - it's just that it's *known in advance* that it will eventually need to to be amended, because it's intended to ***facilitate rapid deployment of an interim solution***. Hence, your "distinction" is a false one - it really just distinguishes low caliber programmers from the good ones!

Comment: Isn't there a software engineering Stack Exchange or some other place more relevant to this where experts are more likely to congregate?

Comment: @StuartF There is are software stacks, but this is also primarily a language centered question, and there is a business language tag (I waffled on where to ask it for a few minutes as well)

Comment: Who is the audience?  Someone who would not like the informality of "This code was quick-and-dirty to meet a deadline and is badly in need of refactoring"?

Comment: If "persistent data" is linked to program parameterization, you may consider the issue as a "*configuration debt*".